# How to keep a socket connection open to send messages back and forth

Tags: perl, sockets, network-programming

I'm writing something to relay work to other machines (similar to gearman) I am doing it to learn about socket programming but I am getting really confused

Desired workflow: 
    [client] -> [server] -> [worker1],[worker2],etc

I'm planning to send thousands of jobs (urls) so I think creating a new socket every single request is overkilling, I want to keep an active connection between server and client and server and workers.

This is my implementation but I know there is a better way to do it, I have looked all over the net to find examples but finally decided to post the question here

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
use feature qw(say);
use strict;

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    LocalHost => '0.0.0.0', LocalPort => '7779',
    Proto => 'tcp', blocking => 1, Reuse => 1, Listen => 5
) or die $!;

while(1)
{
    if(my $client_socket = $socket->accept()  ){
        say "Client connected: " .$client_socket->peerhost . ":" . $client_socket->peerport;

        my $last_msg_time = time;         
        while(1){ #I WILL MOVE THIS LOOP TO A CHILD PROCESS OR A THREAD
            my $data; $client_socket->recv($data,1024);
            if($data eq "*DISCONNECT" || time - $last_msg_time > 10){
                say "Timeout";
                last;
            }
            if($data){
                my $last_msg_time = time;
                say "Received: $data";
                $client_socket->send("OK!");
            }
        }
    }
}

$socket->close;
```

client:

```
use IO::Socket::INET;
use feature qw(say);

my $socket = new IO::Socket::INET (
    PeerHost => '127.0.0.1',PeerPort => '7779',
    Proto => 'tcp', blocking => 1
) or die "Cannot connect to the server $!\n";

$socket->send("hello world");

my $response; $socket->recv($response, 1024);
say "received response: $response";
$socket->send("hi again");

$socket->send("*DISCONNECT");


#shutdown($socket, 1);
$socket->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

The server needs to keep the sockets in a hash map, like this:

```
if (my $client_socket = $socket->accept()) {
    $client_sockets{$client_socket->peerhost . ":" . $client_socket->peerport} = $client_socket;
}
```

and to loop through all entries to check for new data or disconnect requests:

```
foreach my $key (keys %client_sockets) {
    my ($host, $port) = split/:/,$key;
    my $socket = $client_sockets{$key};
    #handle socket
    delete $client_sockets{$key} if $disconnected;
}
```

You probably want to kick a worker thread for each new socket. Store the thread handles likewise in a hash map.